# Why does the push method work on a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var test = $();
test.push( $('div')[0] );
```

This works. Any idea why? 
Since push is a array method, I don't understand why this works in this case, any idea?

Is there a practical use for it since you can use .add() ?

Comment: Is `something` just any arbitrary JavaScript object? What's the result?

Comment: @BoltClock I have edited my question. The jquery selection gets extended with the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They borrow `.push()` from `Array.prototype`.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L70

and

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L296

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/HgS2R/1/

```
var MyObj = function(){};
MyObj.prototype.push = Array.prototype.push;

var inst = new MyObj;

inst.push( "test" );

document.write( inst[ 0 ] + '<br>' + inst.length );  // test, 1
```

*Just be aware that instances of your custom constructor won't behave identically to an actual Array.*

---

**EDIT:**

With respect to the edit in your question, `.push()` is not identical to `.add()`.

The `.push()` method is for adding a DOM element to an existing jQuery object.

The `.add()` method can accept a DOM element, or another jQuery object with 1 or more DOM elements, and it returns a *new* jQuery object with the new elements added.

It's more like a `.concat()`.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the source and found these chunks of code (with comments). Not sure if they answer your question:

```
// Save a reference to some core methods
toString = Object.prototype.toString,
hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
push = Array.prototype.push,
slice = Array.prototype.slice,
trim = String.prototype.trim,
indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf,
```

```
// For internal use only.
// Behaves like an Array's method, not like a jQuery method.
push: push,
sort: [].sort,
splice: [].splice
```

Comment: Yes it helped thank you, but im still confused why they did that.

Comment: @meo: It's a free method. They want to add an item at the end of a set of indexed properties, while updating the `.length`, and that's what `.push()` does. No need to write their own.